# How to print dynamic pdf in React-Native

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, reactjs, react-native

Print Data To PDF in React-Native. I have seen many tutorials but haven't got the exact answer to this question.

**Invoice.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
        import { View, SafeAreaView ,StyleSheet, ScrollView, Button, Platform, Text } from "react-native";
        import { Card } from "react-native-elements";
        import { DataTable } from "react-native-paper";
        import Pdf from "../components/Pdf";
        
        const Invoice = () => {
            return (
              <SafeAreaView>
                <ScrollView>
                  <Card>
                    <Text h3>Invoice #7654</Text>
                      <View>
                            <Text>
                            <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>From:</Text>
                            {"\n"}Tata 56 view Pune
                            {"\n"}Email: sumit@.com
                            {"\n"}Phone: 5252146954
                          </Text>
                       </View>
                    <Pdf />
                  </Card>
                </ScrollView>
              </SafeAreaView>
            );
        }

        export default Invoice
```

**Pdf.js**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Platform, Text } from 'react-native';
import * as Print from 'expo-print';
import { shareAsync } from 'expo-sharing';
import RNPrint from 'react-native-print';
import Invoice from './Invoice';

export default function Pdf() {
  
  
  const printToFile = async () => {
    const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({
      <Invoice />
    });
    console.log('File has been saved to:', uri);
    await shareAsync(uri, { UTI: '.pdf', mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View />
      <Button title="Print to PDF file" onPress={printToFile} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    marginTop: 20
  }
});
```

I want to print the Invoice.js which I am importing in pdf. Any suggestions on how to print PDF in React-Native?

Comment: Hi, how did you solve this problem. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: take backticks(``) and wrap all your code inside that and after that what output do you want to generate like this e.g:- ${this.state.name} @IshaqKamran. If still unclear add a comment I give a small demo.

Comment: give a demo been strugling with this

Comment: okay @louis. here a small eg.:-

`const print=() => {
const html = `
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
 
body {
    background-color: wheat;
   
}
</styles>
<link>
//Your links
</link>
</head>
<body>
//your content
</body>
</html>
`
return html
}`
and after add it to ur print function
const html = this.print()

Comment: @Gaurav i was able to solve this, however thank you